# HTML5 combine multiple canvas and update in realtime

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am trying to combine canvas that change colour in response to consumer's choice. I have placed PNG's onto multiple canvas with transparent backgrounds. I need to combine them and save a png of the final image to pass to the basket and post to my server. Can anyone help? You can see the page and code at http://www.ewe.potberrys.com/colour_image_3.php. Please excuse the quality of the code. I am new :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest do not save the PNG. Just save the colors with your order (you have to do it anyways) and render the helmet in the basket with the same approach you do in the selector tool.

It would probably be possible (but I am not 100% sure) to generate an image on the client side in Chrome and post it via a hidden form, but the stack is so experimental, that it is not ready for production.

A little easier, one can do it with ImageMagic and PHP on the server side. I am not a PHP expert, but you can easily google an example code - there is plenty.

My advice: do not bother. Just have tidy up your JavaScript that renders a helmet to be usable in multiple places with multiple dimensions.